# Marigold buds grow sideways and die

Tags: diagnosis, plant-care, container-gardening, outdoor, marigold

[image]Plants are in 3 gallon pots, outside in full sun, watered and fertilized, and pruned when necessary. I live in S. Florida, so cold is no problem.